# Oracle - missing window specification for this function

Tags: oracle, group-by

I have inherited a oracle database and being used to MySQL I am struggling to get the data I need.

I am trying to get records from TTDINV700732 and TTCCOM001732 where the max(date) in TTDINV700732 is GTEQ one year ago and where there are records in the joined table TTDINV150732 where the date is GTEQ today.

I get the error

`[99999][30484] ORA-30484: missing window specification for this function`

Here is my SQL

```
  SELECT

  first_value(trim("TTDINV700732"."T$ITEM")) AS "item",
  first_value("TTDINV700732"."T$CWAR") AS "whse",
  max("TTDINV700732"."T$TRDT") AS "date",
  first_value("TTCCOM001732"."T$NAMB") AS "business"

  FROM "DB"."TTDINV700732" "TTDINV700732"


  LEFT OUTER JOIN "DB"."TTIITM001732" "TTIITM001732" ON "TTDINV700732"."T$ITEM"="TTIITM001732"."T$ITEM"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "DB"."TTCCOM001732" "TTCCOM001732" ON "TTIITM001732"."T$CPLB"="TTCCOM001732"."T$EMNO"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "DB"."TTDINV150732" "TTDINV150732" ON "TTDINV150732"."T$ITEM"="TTDINV700732"."T$ITEM"


  where "TTDINV700732"."T$TRDT" <= to_date('12 Oct 2016', 'DD MON YYYY')
  and "TTDINV700732"."T$QUAN" < 0
  and "TTDINV150732"."T$DATE" >= to_date('12 Oct 2017','DD MON YYYY')

  group by "TTDINV700732"."T$ITEM", "TTDINV700732"."T$CWAR"
```

Comment: In Oracle `FIRST_VALUE`  analytical function can only be used with a window clause  such as `FIRST_VALUE OVER ( partition by column order by column ) `  . Refer : https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/first-value-and-last-value-analytic-functions for examples

Answer (score 0):

1. *where the max(date) in TTDINV700732 is GTEQ one year ago* (from today)

If you filter that table for `<= to_date('12 Oct 2016', 'DD MON YYYY')` then no maximum can be greater than the date you have specified, is that intentional/correct? OR, do you require a subquery to get the MAX() dates then use `HAVING MAX(T$TRDT) <= to_date('12 Oct 2016', 'DD MON YYYY')` **??**

2. *...joined table TTDINV150732 where the date is GTEQ today*

Should this be equal to today, or greater than and equal **??**

Would something like this work?

```
SELECT
         t700732.t$item AS item 
       , t700732.t$cwar AS whse 
       , t700732.mx_date AS mx_date
       , ttccom001732.t$namb AS business 
FROM (
    SELECT ttdinv700732.t$item  , ttdinv700732.t$cwar, MAX(ttdinv700732.t$trdt) mx_date
    FROM   db.ttdinv700732 
    WHERE  ttdinv700732.t$quan < 0 
    GROUP  BY ttdinv700732.t$item  , ttdinv700732.t$cwar 
    HAVING MAX(ttdinv700732.t$trdt) <= To_date('12 Oct 2016', 'DD MON YYYY') 
    ) t700732
INNER JOIN db.ttdinv150732 ON t700732.t$item = ttdinv150732.t$item
LEFT OUTER JOIN db.ttiitm001732 ON ttdinv700732.t$item = ttiitm001732.t$item 
LEFT OUTER JOIN db.ttccom001732 ON ttiitm001732.t$cplb = ttccom001732.t$emno 
where ttdinv150732.t$date >= To_date('12 Oct 2017', 'DD MON YYYY')
```

You may find it easier to solve it like it was MySQL instead of attempting features of Oracle that you are not familiar with yet.